# Is there anything about my PATH that would cause Ruby not to work?

Tags: ruby, path, rubymine

I followed (or thought I followed) ruby-lang.org's directions for installing the latest, non-system, version of Ruby on my Mac using rbenv. I cannot get my Ruby code files to run, though, and I get the following error message in RubyMine:

Error: Home path (/Users/myname/.rbenv/versions/3.3.0/bin/ruby) for Ruby SDK 'ruby-3.3.0-p0: ver.3.3.0 ( revision 5124f9ac75) p0 (/Users/myname/.rbenv/versions/3.3.0/bin/ruby)' does not exist.

Is there any issue with my PATH, perhaps?

```
/Users/myname/.rbenv/shims:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:eval "$(rbenv init - zsh)":/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/local/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/appleinternal/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Users/myname/.rvm/bin
```

Comment: It's also worth checking `gem env`.

Comment: What is `eval "$(rbenv init - zsh)` doing in your PATH? That's definitely not supposed to be there.